# Does opencl support boolean variables?

Tags: boolean, opencl, abi

Does openCL support boolean variables? I am currently using JOCL (java) to write my openCL calling code and I don't see anything about booleans.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**tl;dr: Yes, but you should avoid it in kernel function signatures.**

Yes; but the size of a `bool` is *not* defined. Therefore, it does not have an associated API type (as what size the value should be is device dependent).

See section 6.1.1 Built-in Scalar Data Type of the OpenCL 1.1 specification for a list of supported scalar types.

From Section 6.8.k

> Arguments to __kernel functions in a program cannot be declared with the built-in
> scalar types bool, half, size_t, ptrdiff_t, intptr_t, and uintptr_t.  The
> size in bytes of these types except half are implementation-defined and in addition can
> also be different for the OpenCL device and the host processor  making it difficult to
> allocate buffer objects to be  passed as arguments to a kernel declared as pointer to these
> type

Comment: I am confused, there is a bool type but I can't use it?

Comment: You can use it _in_ a kernel, but not for transfers or accesses between the host and the OpenCL code on a compute device, as the size is not portably defined.